# Blazor pass and run Task from child component - cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Task<int>'

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

in my parent component i have Task which i want pass to child component.

Parent component:

```
    <ChildComponent ChangePageMethod="@ChangePage" />
    @code {
           public async Task ChangePage(int page)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(page);
           }
     }
```

Child Component:

```
<a @onclick="prevPage">Prev</a>
<a @onclick="nextPage">Next</a>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Page { get; set; } = 3;

    [Parameter]
    public Task ChangePageMethod { get; set; }

    private void prevPage()
    {
        
    }
    private void _nextPage()
    {
        
    }
}
```

For now im getting this error: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Task'

Any tips how to fix it? And how to run task passed from parent with parameter?

Comment: `ChangePageMethod = ChangePage` ChangePage is a method. ChangePageMethod is a Task. So you "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Task'". You'd get that error in C#, without adding blazor to the mix. Did you want to define `public Func<int,Task> ChangePageMethod { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic pattern for this situation is the following code in `ChildComponent`

```
<a @onclick="(e) => prevPage()">Prev</a>
<a @onclick="(e) => nextPage()">Next</a>
```

Use a Lambda expression to sink the mouse event as `e` and then call your methods.

```
[Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> ChangePageMethod { get; set; }

private void nextPage()
{
   // increment the page and call the Event CallBack
   Page++;
   ChangePageMethod.InvokeAsync(Page);
}
```

`nextPage` increments the page counter and then invokes the callback event.  You don't need to use tasks here.  The mouse click event that triggered this is fire-and-forget.

In `ParentComponent` the callback `ChangePageMethod` now passes the page number so `ChangePage` will handle it correctly.

```
public void ChangePage(int page)
{
    Console.WriteLine(page);
}
```

`ChangePage` is the event handler so under normal circumstances you return a void.  If it contains any async code you would label it async.  See below where we use the async `Task.Delay()` to simulate a yielding `Task`.

```
public async void ChangePage(int page)
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
    Console.WriteLine(page);
}
```

`ChangePage` only needs to be declared to return a `Task` if you have code below `InvokeAsync` in `nextPage` or `prevPage` that needs to await whatever you do in `ChangePage` before executing.

Two example patterns for ChangePage below:

```
public async Task ChangePage(int page)
{
    Console.WriteLine(page);
    return Task.Delay(10);
}

public Task ChangePage(int page)
{
    Console.WriteLine(page);
    return Task.Completed;
}
```

Example pattern for prevPage

```
private async void prevPage()
{
   // decrement the page and call the Event CallBack
   Page--;
   await ChangePageMethod.InvokeAsync(Page);
   // Dependant code here
}
```

PS - I think I've got all this code right, but I haven't tested the code so there may be a typo or two.  Check MS Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) on data binding.

Answer (score 0):

The error gives you an exact explanation of what you're trying to do. You're trying to set a method to a `Task` property. `Task` is not what your method is, `Task` is what your method returns. So if you want to store this method, use a type like `Func<int, Task>`.

To run a method stored in this property, you should add the `async` modifier to the method from where you are going to call it, for example `private async void prevPage()`, and inside its body use `await ChangePageMethod(Page);`.

Also, I recommend you to read about async/await and Tasks at leisure.

Answer (score 0):

In your child component, define a parameter of Func<int, Task>

```
[Parameter]
public Func<int, Task> ChangePage { get; set; }
```

This Func can be called like this

```
<button @onclick="async() => await ChangePage(yourPageId)">Change Page</button>
```

In your parent component, define a method

```
private async Task ChangePage(int pageIndex){
  // your implementation
}
```

Then you can pass the method from the parent to the child component like this

```
<ChildComp ChangePage="ChangePage" ></ChildComp>
```